# Symfony2/Twig cache expiration

Tags: php, symfony, twig

Is it possible to set expiration time for Symfony and/or Twig cache. I googled and read the docs for some time and only found the option to auto reload twig templates. As I understand this means it will check templates timestamps on every page load which doesn't seem to be a good idea. It would be great if I could set expiration time and after that period it will check timestamps or even recompile all templates fully.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in your controller before your class:

```
/**
* Controller
* @Cache(expires="tomorrow", public="true")
* @author Author
*/
```

Comment: that's not what I actually mean. I am talking about templates recompiling when they change. Buy default they recompile after cache clear, if I set `auto_reload: true` they will automatically recompile on change. And I ask if I can get something between these options: check for file changes periodically.